# How to color a specific gridline/tickline in 3D Matplotlib Scatter Plot figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter, mplot3d

I am trying to modify the color/thickness of a specific gridline in a 3D matplotlib scatter plot, in this case I want the -30 z axis grid line to be black, bold, or thickened so it stands out amongst the other gridlines.
Here is the basic code seen from the mplot3d scatter plot tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zl, zh)
    scat = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=c, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

I have tried the following:

```
y_min, y_max = scat.axes.get_ylim()
scat.axes.set_ylim([y_min,y_max])
x_min, x_max = scat.axes.get_xlim()
scat.axes.set_xlim([x_min,x_max])

plt.plot([0.0,0.0], [y_min,y_max], 'k-', lw=2)
plt.plot([x_min,x_max], [0.0225,0.0225], 'k-', lw=2)
```

and

```
ax.w_zaxis._axinfo.update({ztick[2] : {'color': (0, 0, 0, 1)}})
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code needed to make the gridline colors changable:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d import Axis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.projections as proj
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter


class axis3d_custom(Axis):
    def __init__(self, adir, v_intervalx, d_intervalx, axes, *args, **kwargs):
        Axis.__init__(self, adir, v_intervalx, d_intervalx, axes, *args, **kwargs)
        self.gridline_colors = []
    def set_gridline_color(self, *gridline_info):
        '''Gridline_info is a tuple containing the value of the gridline to change
        and the color to change it to. A list of tuples may be used with the * operator.'''
        self.gridline_colors.extend(gridline_info)
    def draw(self, renderer):
        # filter locations here so that no extra grid lines are drawn
        Axis.draw(self, renderer)
        which_gridlines = []
        if self.gridline_colors:
            locmin, locmax = self.get_view_interval()
            if locmin > locmax:
                locmin, locmax = locmax, locmin

            # Rudimentary clipping
            majorLocs = [loc for loc in self.major.locator() if
                         locmin <= loc <= locmax]
            for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs):
                for colored_val, color in self.gridline_colors:
                    if val == colored_val:
                        which_gridlines.append((i, color))
            colors = self.gridlines.get_colors()
            for val, color in which_gridlines:
                colors[val] = colorConverter.to_rgba(color)
            self.gridlines.set_color(colors)
            self.gridlines.draw(renderer, project=True)

class XAxis(axis3d_custom):
    def get_data_interval(self):
        'return the Interval instance for this axis data limits'
        return self.axes.xy_dataLim.intervalx

class YAxis(axis3d_custom):
    def get_data_interval(self):
        'return the Interval instance for this axis data limits'
        return self.axes.xy_dataLim.intervaly

class ZAxis(axis3d_custom):
    def get_data_interval(self):
        'return the Interval instance for this axis data limits'
        return self.axes.zz_dataLim.intervalx

class Axes3D_custom(Axes3D):
    """
    3D axes object.
    """
    name = '3d_custom'

    def _init_axis(self):
        '''Init 3D axes; overrides creation of regular X/Y axes'''
        self.w_xaxis = XAxis('x', self.xy_viewLim.intervalx,
                            self.xy_dataLim.intervalx, self)
        self.xaxis = self.w_xaxis
        self.w_yaxis = YAxis('y', self.xy_viewLim.intervaly,
                            self.xy_dataLim.intervaly, self)
        self.yaxis = self.w_yaxis
        self.w_zaxis = ZAxis('z', self.zz_viewLim.intervalx,
                            self.zz_dataLim.intervalx, self)
        self.zaxis = self.w_zaxis

        for ax in self.xaxis, self.yaxis, self.zaxis:
            ax.init3d()
proj.projection_registry.register(Axes3D_custom)
```

Just copy and paste and put at at the top of your file. When you set up your figure, you'll want to use the new name as the projection: `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d_custom')`, and then you can do something like the following to alter the color of gridlines.

```
color = ((-30, 'red'), (-40, (0, 0, 0, 1)))
ax.zaxis.set_gridline_color(*color)
ax.xaxis.set_gridline_color((24, 'blue'))
```

The argument for `set_gridline_color` is a tuple (location, color). You can also use a list of tuples with the * operator.

[image: 3D plot with colored gridlines]

Ta-da!

-------Old Answer-------
Your first attempt looks good, except I think you want to just plot a line from (x_min, y_max, -30) to (x_max, y_max, -30).

```
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim([y_min,y_max])
x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim([x_min,x_max])

plt.plot([x_min,x_max], [y_max,y_max], [-30, -30], 'k-', lw=2)
```

[image: 3d plot]

It's definitely hacky, and you might want to fiddle with the coordinates a bit to see if you can get it to fit better. But it'll do in a pinch, I guess. I'll see if I can figure out a better way.

Comment: Yes, this looks good as I found out myself, but once you start to turn the figure it no longer becomes helpful as it is a line and not on the axis.  Any suggestions for actually coloring or thickening the grid line rather than plotting a new one entirely?

Comment: I added this: plt.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_max], [-30, -30], 'k-', lw = 2)

Comment: I liked this better when I changed lw to 0.5, as well. Still visible, looks more natural.

Comment: Could you please add an image of your figure for visual representation?

Comment: @tylerswright, the good news is that I figured out how to change the color of a gridline! The bad news is that it gets reset when I call plt.show() or plt.savefig(), in a way that looks hard-coded. Doing what you want will likely require messing around with matplotlib's source code. The code you want is in mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axis_3d.py. Look for draw_grid.

Comment: I found a little bit of code under ''' if self.axes._draw_grid: ''', but not sure how that was implemented.  Think you can put up a revised version of your code? @AmyTeegarden

Comment: @tylerswright Yeah, the issue with self.axes._draw_grid is that it sets the color of all the lines to the color in axinfo. At first, I tried modifying the code to only do that if there weren't already the same number of colors as lines, but then the black line disappears if you zoom (thus changing the number of gridlines). I think it's necessary to store some stuff as attributes. I'm going to see if I can figure out a way to do that, and also to avoid messing with the source by making a custom axis class instead. Are you on a deadline?

Comment: No deadline, but obviously the sooner the better.  Thanks for your help, and I will keep researching as well. @AmyTeegarden

Comment: @tylerswright, I don't know if it notifies you when I edit an answer, but I have your solution. No alteration of the code in the matplotlib source folder required. :)

Comment: Awesome!!! That is a great solution, and it works perfectly.  I'll dig into it a little this morning to make sure I follow the changes you made.  I'll comment any further questions I have, and thanks again for the help. @AmyTeegarden