# How to color 3D gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines, matplotlib-3d

I was looking for a way to change the color of a 3D plots gridlines and was unable to find a clean and easy way to do so. The only answer I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684448/how-to-color-a-specific-gridline-tickline-in-3d-matplotlib-scatter-plot-figure) and it came off as a bit complex. I was wondering if there was an easier way to color the gridlines of a 3D plot in matplotlib using `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`

simple example found [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mplot3d-tutorial)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code from the [question you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684448/how-to-color-a-specific-gridline-tickline-in-3d-matplotlib-scatter-plot-figure) is so complex because it colorizes single lines of the grid.

If the aim is to colorize all gridlines simulatneously, you may just use

```
plt.rcParams['grid.color'] = "deeppink"
```

[image]