# Change gridbox color in plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plot_surface produces by default a grey gridbox on the background. I would like to lighten the shade of grey and of the black grid but I can't find how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib color 3D gridlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084987/matplotlib-color-3d-gridlines) As an aside - not plot_surface generates the grid but your axis object defined as 3D projection.

Comment: Not entirely, it changes the grid color only, and permanently (not for just that figure). I also need to change the background of the 3d cube

Comment: As the matplotlib docs explain, [rcParams can be set for individual figures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-rc-settings).

Comment: As for the pane colors, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11448972/8881141